# Parsing pair of floats

Tags: c#, parsing

Given a string like: `"0.123, 0.456"` what is the simplest way to parse the two float values into two variables `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest:

- Split on comma (`string.Split`)
- Trim (`string.Trim`)
- Parse with either `float.Parse` or `float.TryParse`. (If you want an exception to be thrown if the format is incorrect, go for `Parse`. If you want to handle parsing failures as part of your normal control flow, use `TryParse`.)

If the numbers are definitely going to be in that format, explicitly specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Also consider using `decimal` (or `double`) instead of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and try parse each trimmed array item.

```
string[] parts = "0.123, 0.456".Split(new Char [] { ',' });
foreach (string s in parts) 
{
    if (s.Trim() != "")
    {
       var result = float.Parse(s.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // May throw an InvalidCastException
    }
}
```